# Have I been hacked via PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Noticed this in my access logs and after some reading found out it is a possible vulnerability in phpmyadmin, how can I know if they were successful in their attack?

Here are the access logs for this particular set of instructions.

```
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:05 +0000] "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "-"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:05 +0000] "POST /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:07 +0000] "POST /xw.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:07 +0000] "POST /xx.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:08 +0000] "POST /s.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:08 +0000] "POST /w.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:09 +0000] "POST /db.init.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
::1 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:09 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g (internal dummy connection)"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:10 +0000] "POST /db_session.init.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:10 +0000] "POST /sheep.php HTTP/1.1" 302 543 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
::1 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:10 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:11 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g (internal dummy connection)"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:12 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 15959 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:13 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 401 729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:14 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:14 +0000] "GET /pmd/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:14 +0000] "GET /pma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:14 +0000] "GET /PMA/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:15 +0000] "GET /PMA2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:15 +0000] "GET /pmamy/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:15 +0000] "GET /pmamy2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:15 +0000] "GET /mysql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:16 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:16 +0000] "GET /db/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:17 +0000] "GET /dbadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:17 +0000] "GET /web/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:17 +0000] "GET /admin/pma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:17 +0000] "GET /admin/PMA/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:18 +0000] "GET /admin/mysql/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:18 +0000] "GET /admin/mysql2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:18 +0000] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:19 +0000] "GET /admin/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:19 +0000] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:19 +0000] "GET /mysqladmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:19 +0000] "GET /mysql-admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:20 +0000] "GET /phpadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:20 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin0/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:21 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:21 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:21 +0000] "GET /myadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:21 +0000] "GET /myadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:22 +0000] "GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:22 +0000] "GET /phpMyadmin_bak/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:22 +0000] "GET /www/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:22 +0000] "GET /tools/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:23 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:23 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdminold/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:23 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin.old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:24 +0000] "GET /pma-old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:24 +0000] "GET /claroline/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:25 +0000] "GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:25 +0000] "GET /phpma/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:26 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 401 729 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
103.101.177.22 - - [28/Jun/2018:11:52:26 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not a proof for being hacked.
That looks like someone is trying to get access to an installation of phpmyadmin. As phpmyadmin can be included in different ways, which result in different url pathes, he tries all known pathes hoping to get a valid response.
Between the default pathes you can find some pathes for installtion of phpmyadmin as a submodule of a CMS. 
I know TYPO3 and the phpmyadmin module would be at `/typo3conf/ext/phpmyadmin/`, `/typo3/`  normaly is just a symlink into the source of TYPO3, where no external module like phpmyadmin would be.